# Python make a movie of a changing numpy array directly

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, video

I want to make a movie from an actual array of numpy matrices. For instance, frame 0 is:

```
    global_Q_list[0]
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

While frame 5000 looks like:

```
global_Q_list[5000]
array([[8.57716309e-02, 8.20853839e-02, 1.26145944e-01, 2.29583911e-02],
       [5.06244849e-03, 9.06903873e-02, 8.43526776e-02, 2.47270364e-01],
       [3.72547418e-01, 1.28431849e-02, 1.63121207e-02, 1.81253747e-02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 7.79033175e-03, 1.04229209e-05, 1.72459594e-02],
       [8.57223954e-02, 4.79393946e-03, 2.87858885e-04, 9.80675779e-02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [1.32541201e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 4.22892486e-01, 0.00000000e+00],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [0.00000000e+00, 9.30329542e-03, 7.04549482e-03, 1.38380103e-01],
       [1.14731701e-02, 2.85900491e-01, 9.86552196e-03, 1.48614327e-02],
       [1.35700375e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.48956433e-01, 0.00000000e+00],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 5.89541441e-01, 0.00000000e+00],
       [2.98470415e-01, 9.36288568e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.12272268e-01],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]])
```

I literally want a video that shows the numbers as they change where every element of the list is a frame.

I know how to do it if it was a grayscale "image" from cv2 but in this case I want the actual numbers.

Comment: Consider recording a [matplotlib animation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html) with heatmap or text labels placed at axes positions.

Answer (score 1):

You should normalize in the same way **each and every frame** to a range from `0` to `255`.

So, take the minumum of each frame and get the absolute minumum. Then do the same with the maximum and use thos values to normalize.

---

For example, let's say that the last frame contains the absolute minumum and absolute maximum, here is how to normalize:

```
min_ = ary.min()
min_ #=> 0.0
max_ = ary.max()
max_ #=> 0.936288568
```

Since the minimum is 0.0, the normalization is straightforward:

```
normalized_frame = (ary * 255 / max_).astype(np.uint8)
normalized_frame
#array([[ 23,  22,  34,   6],
#       [  1,  24,  22,  67],
#       [101,   3,   4,   4],
#       [  0,   2,   0,   4],
#       [ 23,   1,   0,  26],
#       [  0,   0,   0,   0],
#       [ 36,   0, 115,   0],
#       [  0,   0,   0,   0],
#       [  0,   2,   1,  37],
#       [  3,  77,   2,   4],
#       [ 36,   0,  40,   0],
#       [  0,   0,   0,   0],
#       [  0,   0,   0,   0],
#       [  0,   0, 160,   0],
#       [ 81, 255,   0,  57],
#       [  0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

**Don't forget to convert to `uint8`: `.astype(np.uint8)`.**

---

> I know how to do it if it was a grayscale "image" from cv2 but in this
> case I want the actual numbers.

so I skip the movie generation using opencv.